# "Read" XML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Still playing with Chrome Extension and have a little problem when I want to get some information from an XML file. Here is how the XML look :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<objects>
    <url>
        <domain>...</domain>
        <nb_clics>...</nb_clics>
        <alias>...</alias>
        <title>...</title>
        <source>...</source>
        <description />
    </url>
</objects>
```

I've tried this but, no result :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                width:160px;
            }
            p {
                font-weight:bold;
                margin-bottom:0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DOMImplementation(sUrl, fCallback) {
            var dom;
            if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                dom = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                dom.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(dom.readyState == 4) {
                        fCallback(dom);
                    }
                };
            }
            else if(document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
                dom = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
                dom.onload = function() { 
                    fCallback(dom); 
                }
            }   
            else {
                alert("ERROR");
                return;
            } 
            dom.load(sUrl);
        }

        function shrimit() {
            var nicknick = localStorage["nick_name"];
            var apiapi = localStorage["api_key"];
            var yourc = document.getElementById("your");

            chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
                var tablink = tab.url;
                if(!nicknick || !apiapi){
                    yourc.setAttribute("value","Set the options");
                } else {
                    DOMImplementation("post.xml", getData);
                    function getData(oData) {
                        var tablink2 = oData.getElementsByTagName("alias")[0].firstChild.data;
                        yourc.setAttribute("value",tablink2);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <body onload="shrimit()">
        <input id="your" name="your" type="text" value="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: What does "no result" mean exactly? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: If it's a chrome extension why would you use ActiveX? That's an IE technology. I guess you probably just copied and pasted some code and have no idea just what you are doing.

Comment: +1 to apphacker for the cold hard truth

Comment: @Mike Robinson: Yeah it's the cold hard truth, that's why the OP is asking for help!  That's kind of the point of SO isn't it?

Comment: I'm quite a noob in JS, just nw the base, I've tried this because nothing else were working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `XMLHttpRequest` to load an XML file. This is standardised and reliable across browsers. `document.implementation.createDocument ... load` is not.

(You may get an HTMLDocument instead of a plain XML Document. Normally sniff for `DOMParser` before falling back to `document.implementation.createDocument`. Also `createDocument('', '', null);` is invalid: you can't have an empty-string root element name. Use `createDocument(null, 'name', null)`. Also, finally, best not use the name `DOMImplementation` because that's the name of a built-in interface/class present in Chrome and some others.)

Finally, using a `function` statement inside an `else` clause is invalid in JavaScript. Browsers tend to allow it but with variable results. Either declare the function at the top level, or use an inline function expression.

Comment: It's for a Chrome Extension, he doesn't have to fall back on anything. Just use what's available on Chrome.

Comment: Yep, it works with this :

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","post.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send("");
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
var tablink2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("alias")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

Thanks